# How to use JavaScript code in angular to create new folders?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am trying to create new folders into my Angular project files (src/assets/images/NewFolder) based on the user input.

I have tried to add java script file in my assets folder

```
var fs = require('fs');
fs.mkdirSync('d:/stuff');`
```

and then added the reference in angular.json file:

```
"scripts": [
  "src/assets/test.js"
]`
```

Then I need to run this in my ts file but I don't know how? I don't have a function in the java script file above.

Comment: Is this within Angular logic running on the client? If so, then you will not be able to update the file system on the host machine in any way - for security reasons.

Comment: I have property webpage and I have a button to add new property and there I am adding images for that new property. I want to create new folder with the property name and add these images in the new folder. is there a way to create folders in angular other than this way?

Comment: I would strongly suggest you use a database/server side storage for this. Putting them on the client side is not a workable solution.